# Importing Fragment Library

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment called HomeFragment. I initially imported this library with it:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

When I used the FragmentTransaction class in my MainActivity to replace this fragment, I kept getting an error at this point in my code

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,homeFragment);//***Syntax Error Cannot Resolve Method
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

When I changed the my library to

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

The error went away. Does anybody know why FragmentTransaction does not recognize a Fragment using the support Library when the replace method is called? Also, let's say I did need to use this support library what should I use to replace one fragment with another since FragmentTransaction does not work? Thank you.

Comment: wrong 2nd argument found, required android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.